# Distance Variable in front or back pages

Tags: variable

I want to use variable VARX of front/ back pages

Example: in front pages: varx = 5cm

In back pages: varx = 10cm

My minimal code (Varx is always = 5cm)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{datatool,filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{test1.csv}
Acol, Bcol
Ax,Bx
Ay,By
A1,B22
A2,B44
A3,B11
\end{filecontents*}
\DTLloaddb{mydata}{test1.csv}
\expandafter\def\csname varx\endcsname{10cm}
\begin{document}

\DTLforeach{mydata}{\A=Acol,\B=Bcol}%
{%
 \A \hspace{\csname varx\endcsname} \B 
 \newpage
}%

\end{document}
```

How can \hspace{\csname varx\endcsname} change if page = front/back?
Use macro if any

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I propose doing this with the `changepage` package. With option `strict` as used below, it uses LaTeX labels in order to circumvent the asynchronous nature of TeX typesetting;<sup>1</sup> therefore, at least two compilations are needed:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{datatool}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage[strict]{changepage}

\begin{filecontents*}{test2.csv}
Acol, Bcol
Ax,Bx
Ay,By
A1,B22
A2,B44
A3,B11
\end{filecontents*}

\DTLloaddb{mydata}{test2.csv}

\newlength{\lengthForOddPages}
\newlength{\lengthForEvenPages}

\setlength{\lengthForOddPages}{5cm}
\setlength{\lengthForEvenPages}{10cm}

\newcommand*{\pageDependent}{%
  \ifoddpage
    \expandafter
    \lengthForOddPages
  \else
    \expandafter
    \lengthForEvenPages
  \fi
}

\begin{document}

\DTLforeach*{mydata}{\A=Acol,\B=Bcol}%
{%
 \A \checkoddpage\hspace{\pageDependent} \B
 \newpage
}%

\end{document}
```

Of course, you could also define `\pageDependent` this way:

```latex
\newcommand*{\pageDependent}{\ifoddpage 5cm\else 10cm\fi\relax}
```

in case you don't want the indirection. The `\relax` will stop TeX's 〈glue〉-reading process. Otherwise, in some contexts where TeX is reading a 〈glue〉,<sup>2</sup> particular inputs such as `\pageDependent plus ...` or `\pageDependent minus ...` could expand the `...` looking for stretch or shrink components of the 〈glue〉 starting with the expansion of `\pageDependent` (this can happen even if `plus` and `minus` aren't written explicitly as here).

---

**Footnotes**

1. If you use `\thepage` directly inside a paragraph, it will expand to the number of the page TeX is currently working on, but as the paragraph may be split across several pages, the printed page number may differ from the actual page the result is written to. This is because the places where lines are broken, as well as the number of lines in a paragraph, aren't known until TeX has read and processed the whole paragraph. So, if the paragraph starts when TeX is working on page 9 but spans pages 9 and 10, a naive use of `\thepage` could print the number 9 on page 10. The technique using labels (as used by `changepage` with the `strict` option) prevents this problem from happening. Also, some commands such as `\protected@write` take care to expand `\thepage` late enough that its expansion does correspond to the actual page (this is thanks to how `\write` works as opposed to `\immediate\write`, and special handling of `\thepage` in the definition of `\protected@write`).
2. Not inside the argument of `\hspace`, though; so, there would be no problem even without `\relax` in this particular example.

Answer (score 1):

What about something like this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{datatool,filecontents,lastpage,bophook}
\begin{filecontents*}{test2.csv}
Acol, Bcol
Ax,Bx
Ay,By
A1,B22
A2,B44
A3,B11
\end{filecontents*}
\DTLloaddb{mydata}{test2.csv}
\xdef\varx{10cm}
\AtBeginPage{%
\ifnum\thepage=0
\xdef\varx{10cm}
\else
\ifnum\thepage=\pageref{LastPage}
\xdef\varx{10cm}
\fi
\xdef\varx{3cm}
\fi
}
\begin{document}

\DTLforeach{mydata}{\A=Acol,\B=Bcol}%
{%
 \A \hspace{\varx} \B 
 \newpage
}%

\end{document}
```

PS: You can still use your `\csname` command instead of my `\xdef` but I don't really see a reason