# tcolorbox: specific width and height settings for odd and even pages

Tags: tcolorbox, page, variable

Starting from this solution to my older post: [Distance Variable in front or back pages](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/499653/distance-variable-in-front-or-back-pages/499658#499658), how can I set the width and height of a `tcolorbox` in a way that depends on whether the box is put on an odd page or on an even page?

I propose to start from the following code, which is based on the code from the answer in the above link:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{datatool}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage[strict]{changepage}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\begin{filecontents*}{test1.csv}
Acol, Bcol,Ccol
Ax,Bx,1
Ay,By,3
A1,B22,1
A2,B44,2
A3,B11,3
\end{filecontents*}

\DTLloaddb{mydata1}{test1.csv}

\newlength{\xlengthForOddPages}
\newlength{\xlengthForEvenPages}
\newlength{\ylengthForOddPages}
\newlength{\ylengthForEvenPages}

\setlength{\xlengthForOddPages}{2cm}
\setlength{\xlengthForEvenPages}{10cm}
\setlength{\ylengthForOddPages}{1.5cm}
\setlength{\ylengthForEvenPages}{5cm}

\newcommand*{\xpageDependent}{%
  \ifoddpage
    \expandafter
    \xlengthForOddPages
  \else
    \expandafter
    \xlengthForEvenPages
  \fi
}

\newcommand*{\ypageDependent}{%
  \ifoddpage
    \expandafter
    \ylengthForOddPages
  \else
    \expandafter
    \ylengthForEvenPages
  \fi
}

\begin{document}

\DTLforeach*{mydata1}{\A=Acol,\B=Bcol,\C=Ccol}%
{%
  \begin{tcolorbox}[width=\xpageDependent,height=\ypageDependent,title={Title}]
  %\begin{tcolorbox}[width=\checkoddpage{\xpageDependent},height=\checkoddpage{\ypageDependent},title={title}]
    \C
  \end{tcolorbox}
  \newpage
}%

\end{document}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I propose two solutions.

## Using `tcolorbox`'s `if odd page` option

`tcolorbox` has special options to run different code depending on whether the box is on an odd page or on an even page. Here, we use `if odd page` to set the `width` and `height` options in a page-dependent way. In case you have breakable boxes, read section *Even and Odd Pages* of the [`tcolorbox` manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/tcolorbox/tcolorbox.pdf) (you might be interested in using `if odd page*`, depending on what you want for split parts).

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{datatool}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}

\begin{filecontents*}{test1.csv}
Acol, Bcol,Ccol
Ax,Bx,1
Ay,By,3
A1,B22,1
A2,B44,2
A3,B11,3
\end{filecontents*}

\DTLloaddb{mydata1}{test1.csv}

\newlength{\xlengthForOddPages}
\newlength{\xlengthForEvenPages}
\newlength{\ylengthForOddPages}
\newlength{\ylengthForEvenPages}

\setlength{\xlengthForOddPages}{2cm}
\setlength{\xlengthForEvenPages}{10cm}
\setlength{\ylengthForOddPages}{1.5cm}
\setlength{\ylengthForEvenPages}{5cm}

\begin{document}

\DTLforeach*{mydata1}{\A=Acol,\B=Bcol,\C=Ccol}%
{%
\begin{tcolorbox}[
  if odd page={width=\xlengthForOddPages,
               height=\ylengthForOddPages}%
              {width=\xlengthForEvenPages,
               height=\ylengthForEvenPages},
  title={Title}]
  \C
\end{tcolorbox}
\newpage
}

\end{document}
```

## Using `tcolorbox`'s `phantom` option and `\ifoddpage`

We can still use the machinery from [that answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/499653/distance-variable-in-front-or-back-pages/499658#499658) with `tcolorbox`, but we need to ensure that `\checkoddpage` is called:

- before the corresponding uses of `\xpageDependent` or `\ypageDependent`, and
- in a place where we can be sure that the `\checkoddpage` call will be on the **same page** as the `tcolorbox`.

This can be done using `tcolorbox`'s `phantom` option, it is clearly designed for this kind of use:<sup>1</sup>

> Labels are ensured to reference the correct page number.

(see *Counters, Labels, and References* in the [`tcolorbox` manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/tcolorbox/tcolorbox.pdf))

One difficulty with this option is that the user-provided code is run *inside a TeX group,* however the assignment done by `\checkoddpage` that sets the conditional is *local* (I mean, the assignment that says whether `\ifoddpage` is made `\let`-equal to `\iftrue` or to `\iffalse`). Therefore, if we use this technique, we need to globally propagate the `\ifoddpage` “flag” that `\checkoddpage` sets locally. This can be done as follows:

```latex
\newcommand*{\mycheckoddpage}{%
  \checkoddpage
  \global\let\ifmyoddpage=\ifoddpage
}
```

This way, the globally-set flag `\ifmyoddpage` will be visible outside the group started by the `phantom` option. Then we just need to test this flag inside the definitions of `\xpageDependent` and `\ypageDependent`.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{datatool}
\usepackage[strict]{changepage}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}

\begin{filecontents*}{test1.csv}
Acol, Bcol,Ccol
Ax,Bx,1
Ay,By,3
A1,B22,1
A2,B44,2
A3,B11,3
\end{filecontents*}

\DTLloaddb{mydata1}{test1.csv}

\newlength{\xlengthForOddPages}
\newlength{\xlengthForEvenPages}
\newlength{\ylengthForOddPages}
\newlength{\ylengthForEvenPages}

\setlength{\xlengthForOddPages}{2cm}
\setlength{\xlengthForEvenPages}{10cm}
\setlength{\ylengthForOddPages}{1.5cm}
\setlength{\ylengthForEvenPages}{5cm}

\newif\ifmyoddpage              % always set globally, contrary to \ifoddpage

\newcommand*{\xpageDependent}{%
  \ifmyoddpage
    \expandafter
    \xlengthForOddPages
  \else
    \expandafter
    \xlengthForEvenPages
  \fi
}

\newcommand*{\ypageDependent}{%
  \ifmyoddpage
    \expandafter
    \ylengthForOddPages
  \else
    \expandafter
    \ylengthForEvenPages
  \fi
}

\newcommand*{\mycheckoddpage}{%
  \checkoddpage
  \global\let\ifmyoddpage=\ifoddpage
}

\begin{document}

\DTLforeach*{mydata1}{\A=Acol,\B=Bcol,\C=Ccol}%
{%
\begin{tcolorbox}[phantom={\mycheckoddpage},
                  width=\xpageDependent,height=\ypageDependent,
                  title={Title}]
  \C
\end{tcolorbox}
\newpage
}

\end{document}
```

Note: one could also define `\mycheckoddpage` as follows, with the same result:

```latex
\newcommand*{\mycheckoddpage}{%
  \checkoddpage
  \ifoddpage
    \global\myoddpagetrue       % global assignment
  \else
    \global\myoddpagefalse      % global assignment
  \fi
}
```

## Screenshots

Both examples given above produce the same output. Arranging this output with Gimp to have all boxes on the same image (to avoid showing you five almost-blank pages here), one gets:

[image: All boxes on the same image]

---

**Footnote**

1. `\checkoddpage` works by setting a new label wherever it is used, and testing whether the page number for this label is odd or even.