# Ifoddpage statement inside switch case

Tags: conditionals, lengths, variable, layout

Continuation of topics 
[tcolorbox: specific width and height settings for odd and even pages](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/499716/tcolorbox-specific-width-and-height-settings-for-odd-and-even-pages/499730#499730) and [Distance Variable in front or back pages](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/499653/distance-variable-in-front-or-back-pages/499658#499658).

I'd like to set lengths conditionally based on the expansion of a macro (`\C` here, which is set by `datatool` in my code) and whether we are on an odd or even page:

```
\C = 1 & ifoddpage = true  => \xLength = 2cm, \yLength = 1.5cm
\C = 1 & ifoddpage = false => \xLength = 4cm, \yLength = 2cm
\C = 2 & ifoddpage = true  => \xLength = 3cm, \yLength = 2cm
\C = 2 & ifoddpage = false => \xLength = 5cm, \yLength = 3cm
\C = 3 & ifoddpage = true  => \xLength = 4cm, \yLength = 3cm
\C = 3 & ifoddpage = false => \xLength = 4cm, \yLength = 1.5cm
…
\C = 10...
```

Here is minimal code based on code from the above links:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{datatool}
\usepackage[strict]{changepage}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage[absolute,overlay]{textpos}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\begin{filecontents*}{test1.csv}
Acol, Bcol,Ccol
Ax,Bx,1
Ay,By,3
A1,B22,1
A2,B44,2
A3,B11,3
A4,B55,4
\end{filecontents*}

\DTLloaddb{mydata1}{test1.csv}

\newlength{\xlengthForOddPages}
\newlength{\xlengthForEvenPages}
\newlength{\ylengthForOddPages}
\newlength{\ylengthForEvenPages}

\setlength{\xlengthForOddPages}{2cm}
\setlength{\xlengthForEvenPages}{10cm}
\setlength{\ylengthForOddPages}{1.5cm}
\setlength{\ylengthForEvenPages}{5cm}

\newif\ifmyoddpage              % always set globally, contrary to \ifoddpage

\newcommand*{\xpageDependent}{%
  \ifmyoddpage
    \expandafter
    \xlengthForOddPages
  \else
    \expandafter
    \xlengthForEvenPages
  \fi
}

\newcommand*{\ypageDependent}{%
  \ifmyoddpage
    \expandafter
    \ylengthForOddPages
  \else
    \expandafter
    \ylengthForEvenPages
  \fi
}

\newcommand*{\mycheckoddpage}{%
  \checkoddpage
  \global\let\ifmyoddpage=\ifoddpage
}

\newlength{\xLength}
\newlength{\yLength}

\begin{document}

\DTLforeach*{mydata1}{\A=Acol,\B=Bcol,\C=Ccol}%
{%
\begin{tcolorbox}[phantom={\mycheckoddpage},
                  width=\xpageDependent,height=\ypageDependent,
                  title={Title}]
  \C
\end{tcolorbox}
% --> Here, \xLength and \yLength should be set according
%     to the conditions described above. <--
\begin{textblock*}{5cm}(\xLength,\yLength)
\color{red} text abc
\end{textblock*}

\newpage
}
\end{document}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you sure that the width of the `tcolorbox` should be the same as the horizontal offset of your text positioned with `textblock*` (your example and text before the example use `\xpageDependent` for both)? Same question for `\ypageDependent`, of course. (Also, `\xpageDependent` and `\ypageDependent` should be used only we you can be sure that the most recent call to `\mycheckoddpage` placed its internal label on the same page. I assume this is the case here for their second use, i.e., in the arguments of `\begin{textblock*}`.

Comment: [continuation of the previous comment]  In other words, you can guarantee that the `textblock*` is on the same page as the corresponding `tcolorbox`.) Or maybe you want different lengths, but obtain these through a redefinition of `\xpageDependent` and `\ypageDependent` between the `tcolorbox` and when the `textblock*` is set up?

Comment: @frougon should be different length. I just want to test. Sorry & Thanks

Comment: Since the `tcolorbox` doesn't seem to play a significant role here, I believe one might want to remove it from the question. Of course, the screenshots in my answer would then need to be redone (changing the code is quicker)...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I correctly understood your needs, the following should do what you want:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{datatool}
\usepackage[strict]{changepage}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage[absolute,overlay]{textpos}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{xparse}

\begin{filecontents*}{test1.csv}
Acol, Bcol,Ccol
Ax,Bx,1
Ay,By,3
A1,B22,1
A2,B44,2
A3,B11,3
\end{filecontents*}
% If you include a line such as 'A4,B55,4' without saying how \xLength and
% \yLength should be set in this case, you'll get the error message:
%
%   Package lforti Error: Encountered value '4', but no case was written for it.

\DTLloaddb{mydata1}{test1.csv}

\newlength{\xlengthForOddPages}
\newlength{\xlengthForEvenPages}
\newlength{\ylengthForOddPages}
\newlength{\ylengthForEvenPages}

\setlength{\xlengthForOddPages}{2cm}
\setlength{\xlengthForEvenPages}{10cm}
\setlength{\ylengthForOddPages}{1.5cm}
\setlength{\ylengthForEvenPages}{5cm}

\newif\ifmyoddpage              % always set globally, contrary to \ifoddpage

\newcommand*{\xpageDependent}{%
  \ifmyoddpage
    \expandafter
    \xlengthForOddPages
  \else
    \expandafter
    \xlengthForEvenPages
  \fi
}

\newcommand*{\ypageDependent}{%
  \ifmyoddpage
    \expandafter
    \ylengthForOddPages
  \else
    \expandafter
    \ylengthForEvenPages
  \fi
}

\newcommand*{\mycheckoddpage}{%
  \checkoddpage
  \global\let\ifmyoddpage=\ifoddpage
}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\msg_new:nnn { lforti } { unhandled-value }
  { Encountered~value~'\exp_not:n~{#1}',~but~no~case~was~written~for~it. }

\tl_new:N \l__lforti_cond_length_setup_conds_tl
\seq_new:N \l__lforti_cond_length_setup_tmpa_seq
\seq_new:N \l__lforti_cond_length_setup_tmpb_seq

% Flexible length setup that may depend on whether it is called on an odd page
% or on an even page.
%
% #1: a LaTeX length command (or a TeX \skipdef token) to set according to
%     #2 and #3
% #2: the value to test against
% #3: a comma list describing the different cases:
%
%     {
%       {value_1, length-for-odd-pages, length-for-even-pages},
%       {value_2, length-for-odd-pages, length-for-even-pages},
%       ...
%       {value_n, length-for-odd-pages, length-for-even-pages},
%     }
%
% #2 is compared against value_1, value_2, ..., value_n to determine a
% matching “line”, then length command #1 is set to the length-for-odd-pages or
% length-for-even-pages of the matching line, depending on whether the label set
% by \checkoddpage (used at the beginning of the function) is located on an
% odd page or on an even page.
\cs_new_protected:Npn \lforti_cond_length_setup:Nnn #1#2#3
  {
    \checkoddpage               % make sure it is used on the relevant page
    \seq_set_from_clist:Nn \l__lforti_cond_length_setup_tmpa_seq {#3}
    \tl_clear:N \l__lforti_cond_length_setup_conds_tl

    \seq_map_inline:Nn \l__lforti_cond_length_setup_tmpa_seq
      {
        \seq_set_from_clist:Nn \l__lforti_cond_length_setup_tmpb_seq {##1}
        \tl_put_right:Nx \l__lforti_cond_length_setup_conds_tl
          {
            % Value to check against
            { \seq_item:Nn \l__lforti_cond_length_setup_tmpb_seq { 1 } }
            { % Corresponding setup code for #1
              \exp_not:n { \skip_set:Nn #1 }
                {
                  \seq_item:Nn
                    \l__lforti_cond_length_setup_tmpb_seq
                    { \ifoddpage 2 \else 3 \fi }
                }
            }
          }
      }

    % Handle value #2 according to the cases described by
    % \l__lforti_cond_length_setup_conds_tl, which was assembled from #3
    \str_case:nVF {#2} \l__lforti_cond_length_setup_conds_tl
      { \msg_error:nnn { lforti } { unhandled-value } {#2} }
  }

\cs_generate_variant:Nn \lforti_cond_length_setup:Nnn { Nx }

% Same as \lforti_cond_length_setup:Nnn (see above), except that the second
% argument will be fully expanded (\lforti_cond_length_setup:Nnn will only see
% the *result* of this expansion in its #2).
\NewDocumentCommand \lforticondlengthsetup { m m m }
  {
    \lforti_cond_length_setup:Nxn #1 {#2} {#3}
  }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\newlength{\xLength}
\newlength{\yLength}

\begin{document}

\DTLforeach*{mydata1}{\A=Acol,\B=Bcol,\C=Ccol}%
{%
\lforticondlengthsetup{\xLength}{\C}{%
  {1, 2cm, 4cm}, % When \C expands to 1, use 2cm on odd pages, 4cm on even pages
  {2, 3cm, 5cm}, % When \C expands to 2, use 3cm on odd pages, 5cm on even pages
  {3, 4cm, 4cm}, % When \C expands to 3, use 4cm on all pages
}%
\lforticondlengthsetup{\yLength}{\C}{% analogous setup for \yLength
  {1, 1.5cm, 2cm},
  {2, 2cm, 3cm},
  {3, 3cm, 1.5cm},
}%
\begin{textblock*}{5cm}(\xLength,\yLength)
  \color{blue!50!black}%
  \noindent
  \texttt{\string\xLength} = \the\xLength\\
  \texttt{\string\yLength} = \the\yLength
\end{textblock*}

\begin{tcolorbox}[phantom={\mycheckoddpage},
                  width=\xpageDependent,height=\ypageDependent,
                  title={Title}]
  \C
\end{tcolorbox}

\newpage
}

\end{document}
```

Here is the top of each page:

[image: Page 1]

---

[image: Page 2]

---

[image: Page 3]

---

[image: Page 4]

---

[image: Page 5]

My code relies on a flexible length-setting command that I called `\lforticondlengthsetup`. This commands expects its first argument to be a LaTeX length command (or a TeX `\skipdef` token). It fully expands its second argument and compares the result against the first element of each sublist specified in the third argument. For instance, `\xLength` and `\yLength` are set this way to follow the specifications from your question:

```latex
\lforticondlengthsetup{\xLength}{\C}{%
  {1, 2cm, 4cm}, % When \C expands to 1, use 2cm on odd pages, 4cm on even pages
  {2, 3cm, 5cm}, % When \C expands to 2, use 3cm on odd pages, 5cm on even pages
  {3, 4cm, 4cm}, % When \C expands to 3, use 4cm on all pages
}%
\lforticondlengthsetup{\yLength}{\C}{% analogous setup for \yLength
  {1, 1.5cm, 2cm},
  {2, 2cm, 3cm},
  {3, 3cm, 1.5cm},
```

You have to ensure that such length setup commands are issued on the same page where `\xLength` and `\yLength` are used. This should be the case in the full document I gave above.

The length values (second and third element of each sublist present in the third argument of `\lforticondlengthsetup`) can be anything that is a valid LaTeX3 〈skip expression〉. For instance, the following code is valid as long as:

- `\xLength` and `\yLength` have been declared with `\newlength`;
- `\someMacro` recursively expands to either `1`, or `foo`, or `bar baz` (in your example, this role is played by the `\C` macro that expands to values located in the third column of your `.csv` file).

```latex
\lforticondlengthsetup{\yLength}{\someMacro}{
  {1, 0.7\xLength, 2cm plus 0.1cm minus 0.2cm},
  {foo, 2cm plus 1fill, 0pt plus 3fill},
  {bar baz, 3cm plus 1fil minus 0.2fill, 1.5cm},
}
```

Finally, since `\checkoddpage` uses a label/ref mechanism, don't forget that you need to compile several times—normally only twice—to get reliable results!

Comment: awesome, super hero. Do you have other solution for set "\lforticondlengthsetup{\xLength}{\C}{" not in loop of \DTLforeach*? \lforticondlengthsetup{\xLength}{\C}{%
  {1, 2cm, 4cm}, % When \C expands to 1, use 2cm on odd pages, 4cm on even pages
  {2, 3cm, 5cm}, % When \C expands to 2, use 3cm on odd pages, 5cm on even pages
  {3, 4cm, 4cm}, % When \C expands to 3, use 4cm on all pages
}%

Comment: Is your code can same way for 4 variable? xLength,yLength, aLength,bLength? Thanks

Comment: Yes, `\aLength`, `\bLength`, etc. should be quite fine as long as you have declared them with `\newlength`. `\lforticondlengthsetup` is fairly generic: you can use it with *any LaTeX length command* in the first argument (and you can even use lengths commands in the third argument: see the `0.7\xLength` in the last example of my answer). The command works outside the loop too, this makes no difference.

Comment: Also, if this makes things easier for you, it's quite simple to change the syntax from `\lforticondlengthsetup{\someLength}{...}{...}` to `\lforticondlengthsetup{someLength}{...}{...}` (notice the missing ``\`` in the second one). This can make things slightly easier if you want to “construct” the length command names using macros (for instance, with something like `\lforticondlengthsetup{#1Length}{...}{...}` in the replacement text of one of your macros, where `a`, `x`, `y`, etc., could be passed as values for `#1`). You can always construct such names using `\csname`, but  this requires...

Comment: ...  expanding the `\csname` before `\lforticondlengthsetup` is itself expanded: `\expandafter\lforticondlengthsetup\expandafter{\csname #1Length\endcsname}{...}{...}`.

Comment: I need more time to "eat" your code and your recommend. I tested that cut code block :\lforticondlengthsetup{\xLength}{\C}{%...out of DTLforeach but...wrong result. Can you do it? Thanks

Comment: I did many tests like this one for the final example of my answer, I'm quite sure it works. Maybe `\C` wasn't defined where you used it? Otherwise, post the code at the end of your question (you can remove it later when it's solved). For instance, my final example can only be used at a point where `\someMacro` is defined. Did you compile twice? Any error message?

Comment: This error only: !!!!!! when i use \C or Ccol. Please see image: https://imgur.com/4Av0KdF

Comment: What I said before is that if you intend to write code that can be called like `\foo{a}`, `\foo{b}`, etc. in order to conditionally set `\aLength` , `\bLength`, etc., there is a possible syntax change that can make this easier. The difference is that in order to set `\someLength`, the first argument of `\lforticondlengthsetup` would need to be `someLength` instead of `\someLength`. The current syntax is consistent with LaTeX's `\setlength`, which expects a control sequence token as its first argument, however this makes the kind of thing I described slightly more difficult.

Comment: My code in pastebin: https://pastebin.com/NnL9LG1m

Comment: The screenshot doesn't show the same code as the pastebin (`Ccol` vs. `\C`). The error in the [pastebin code](https://pastebin.com/NnL9LG1m) is that you ask `\lforticondlengthsetup` to expand `\C` at a point where `\C` is undefined (this is just after `\begin{document}`). That's exactly what I warned you against [above](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/499746/ifoddpage-statement-inside-switch-case/499781#comment1262353_499781)...

Comment: When you use `\lforticondlengthsetup{\someLength}{\macro}{
  {1, 2cm, 4cm},
  {2, 3cm, 5cm},
  {3, 4cm, 4cm},
}`, `\macro` must (recursively) expand to either `1`, or `2`, or `3` (first element of each sublist in the third argument). So, you can have before: `\newcommand*{\macro}{2}` or `\renewcommand*{\macro}{3}` for instance, but not `\renewcommand*{\macro}{4}` (for this, you need to add a new sublist that handles the case of `4`).

Comment: By the way, the checked value is not limited to integers. You could say: `\newcommand*{\macro}{Foo bar baz} \lforticondlengthsetup{\someLength}{\macro}{{abc, 2cm, 4cm},
  {Def Ghi, 3cm, 5cm},
  {Foo bar baz, 4cm, 4cm}}`